# Register a container (IoC) in a class library?

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm creating an n-tier application with the following sections.

- MyApp.DAL - data access layer (EF 5, SQL back end)
- MyApp.BLL - business layer
- MyApp.WcfService - Services layer
- MyApp.WpfClient - front end
- MyApp.Models is a shared project that holds all of the POCOs.

I'll give an example of the "Country" entity through each layer. First is the model. Please note that StatefulObject will help me track an entity sate from the disconnected client (per Julia Lerner's programming EF 2nd edition Chapter 18).

```
public class Country : StatefulObject
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the DAL I have an ICountryRepository (basic CRUD) and a CountryRepository. Here is the constructor.

```
public class CountryRepository : ICountryRepository, IDisposable
{
    MyDbContext _db;

    public CountryRepository()
    {
        _db = new MyDbContext();
    }

    //Implement ICountryRepository (basically CRUD), etc...
}
```

My BLL has an ICountryLogic, CountryLogic, IBusinessLayer, and BusinessLayer like so:

```
public class CountryLogic : ICountryLogic
{
    ICountryRepository _countryRepository;

    public CountryLogic(ICountryRepository countryRepository)
    {
        _countryRepository = countryRepository;
    }

    //implement ICountryLogic members, etc...
}

public class BusinessLayer : IBusinessLayer
{
    public ICountryLogic CountryLogic { get; set; }

    public BusinessLayer()
    {
        CountryLogic = new CountryLogic(new CountryRepository());
    }
}
```

Then an example service method that instantiates a new Business layer and does some operation like so:

```
public class CountryService : ICountryService
{
    public IEnumerable<Country> GetAll()
    {
        IBusinessLayer bl = new BusinessLayer();
        return bl.CountryLogic.GetAll();
    }

    //implement other service operations
}
```

Then the WPF client can just use the service like so:

```
CountryServiceClient countryService = new CountryServiceClient();

var countries = countryService.GetAll();
```

Now, before putting the WCF service between the BLL and WPF front end, my WPF front end could just use Dependency Injections and I wouldn't have this ugliness:

```
public class BusinessLayer : IBusinessLayer
{
    public ICountryLogic CountryLogic { get; set; }

    public BusinessLayer()
    {
        CountryLogic = new CountryLogic(new CountryRepository());  // <<<< UGLY HERE
    }
}
```

Instead I would use DI and constructor injection like so:

```
public class BusinessLayer : IBusinessLayer
{
    public ICountryLogic CountryLogic { get; set; }

    public BusinessLayer(ICountryLogic countryLogic)
    {
        CountryLogic = countryLogic;
    }
}
```

Then just register the interfaces and implementations in the container in WPF. My question is how can I register them in the class library (in the BLL)? Since there is no composition root or entry point in a class library I'm not sure how to do it. I'm using SimpleInjector.

Alternatively, I could use DI in the Wcf service, but that would require the service to have a reference to the DAL so it could register the ICountryRepository to a CountryRepository. This doesn't seem right. The service layer should only reference the BLL, which is why I want the DI set up in the BLL. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could try implement a `static BootStrap` method within each layer and chain the calls for registration (passing the container instance down through each method.

`Wpf.Client` calls `Wpf.Service.Bootstrap(container)` which calls `WPF.Bll.Bootstrap(container)` ... ?

This should get you going, but I heartily recommend you read through Stevens articles, they make a lot of sense and once implemented they provide a very flexible architecture.

Comment: I've implemented this and it works fine now but you're right, I'm interested in finding a good small working sample from DAL >> BLL >> Service >> Front end using Command/Query Handler referenced in Steven's answer. I can't quite wrap my head around those articles yet. Are there simple examples using that methodology somewhere?

Comment: For me it was a voyage of discovery spanning 4 months now. Google, stackoverflow and SimpleInjector are all you need ;-)

Comment: @BBauer42: If your application is truly CRUD; don't use commands. But neither should you use service classes (as your `CountryService`). It's just overhead. Just let the UI depend directly on the repository. When you have extra business logic besides simple CRUD operations: use commands instead. Command handlers are your service classes, but focused to solve a single use case. Queries on the other hand, can be applied on every type of application. Even simple CRUD applications tend to get queries that are pretty complex and need all sorts of cross-cutting concerns applied to them.

Answer (score 4):

As I see it, you are missing some abstractions here. The WPF client shouldn't be concerned with the fact that you place a WCF service in between. For instance, instead of having rather ugly `XXXService` classes (such as `CountryService`), consider sending command and query messages over the wire. This way you can define a simple `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` and `IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>` interfaces on which the WPF client can depend. In that case it doesn't have to know whether it communicates over the network or not. These abstractions also give the possibility to add cross-cutting concerns (as decorators) such as the [circuit breaker design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern), which is really useful when working with clients that have an unreliable connection (especially useful with queries). For sending commands, you might be better of with a queue, but this can be implemented as a decorator on the `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interface as well.

Here are some articles that describe these concepts:

- [Meanwhile... on the command side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)
- [Meanwhile... on the query side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)
- [Writing Highly Maintainable WCF Services](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95)

Comment: I've read through these before and can't quite wrap my head around them yet. Is there a simple example somewhere that you can see every later and how they interact? DAL, BLL, Services, Client?

Comment: The [solidservice.codeplex.com](https://solidservices.codeplex.com/) project contains a working VS solution with WCF client and WCF service that communicate through commands and queries.

Comment: The articles linked above are the best I've seen on implementing a .NET layered architecture using SOLID principles. Well worth reading.